# I'm trying to texture a character models face

Tags: texturing, uv

When I go into UV editor and unwrap, the uv map is awfully distorted. Even with seems, Some of the eye doesn't highlight when I choose the eye with the b select short cut. I'd be more then happy to take images and attach them to an Email if anyone is interested in helping me. Thank you.

Comment: Hello :). You can upload images directly into the post - [How to upload images to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/317576/652639). You can also share the .blend file through our local [Blend-Exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)

Answer (score 0):

So, I solved this. first you unwrap your model in the uvmap then take the whole thing and
shrink the map down. Highlight certain parts of the body to figure out where the piece is on the uv map. Then, select all on the model. go to where that part is on the UV map. B select it then shift click any pieces you may have picked up from other body parts. drag it over to an empty space on the uv map and continue this process until you have a comprehensive uv map of your complex Model.